# Как сравнить отдельно объекты двух массивов

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть 2 массива с именами и ценами некоторых предметов (x и ItemPrice).
Для того чтобы у меня были отдельно имена двух массивов, сделал для обоих такие циклы:

```
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
  names = x[i];
  name = names.custom_market_name;
}

for (i = 0; i< ItemPrice.length; i++){
  namess = ItemPrice[i];
  namex = namess.market_name;
}
```

Теперь мне их нужно отдельно последовательно сравнить(имена одного с именами другого массива). Я пытался сделать это такой функцией:

```
function OnGoPressed(){
  var ln1 = namex.length, ln2 = name.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < ln1; ++i){
    cache = namex[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < ln2; ++j){
      if (cache == name[j]){
        console.log('найдено совпадение: ' + cache);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

но результата 0.

Comment: Из вашего кода не понятно что из себя представляет `custom_market_name` и `market_name`.

Comment: это название объектов, с какими-то значениями, а именно с именами  предметов. ну по сути это так выглядит {"market_name":"ыфафы","price":"241421"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваши переменные `name` и `namex` - это не массивы, а имена последних элементов в соответствующих массивах.

```
var namesX = x.map(function(item){ return item.custom_market_name; });
var namesIP = ItemPrice.map(function(item){ return item.market_name; });

for (var i = 0; i < namesX.length; i++) {
  if (namesIP.indexOf(namesX[i]) != -1)
    console.log('найдено совпадение: ' + namesX[i]);
}
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, долго мучился с этим

Comment: @Ярослав На здоровье. Успехов!